# Error while Debugging application on Windows OS or Android

Tags: react-native

I'am having a problem with JS Debugger on Windows or Android, when I debug the app crashes. Every time I try to reopen it, the app crashes. This is my log cat:

```
2019-02-04 12:48:27.135 26780-26833/com.cmcj E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
    Process: com.cmcj, PID: 26780
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;
        at io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebaseModule.getConstants(RNFirebaseModule.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.getConstants(JavaModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cmcj-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cmcj-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.cmcj-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebaseModule.getConstants(RNFirebaseModule.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.getConstants(JavaModuleWrapper.java:138) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the linking went wrong after linking firebase. You need to make sure that everything is in place in MainApplication (especially the namespaces from where classes are taken).